# Python: concat rows of two dataframes where not all columns are the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reindex

I have two dataframes:

EDIT:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index = [0,1,2], columns=['timestamp', 'order_id', 'account_id', 'USD', 'CAD'])
df1['timestamp']=['2022-01-01','2022-01-02','2022-01-03']
df1['account_id']=['usdcad','usdcad','usdcad']
df1['order_id']=['11233123','12313213','12341242']
df1['USD'] = [1,2,3]
df1['CAD'] = [4,5,6]
df1:
    timestamp   account_id order_id  USD CAD
0   2022-01-01  usdcad     11233123  1   4
1   2022-01-02  usdcad     12313213  2   5
2   2022-01-03  usdcad     12341242  3   6

df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = [0,1], columns = ['timestamp','account_id', 'currency','balance'])
df2['timestamp']=['2021-12-21','2021-12-21']
df2['account_id']=['usdcad','usdcad']
df2['currency'] = ['USD', 'CAD']
df2['balance'] = [2,3]
df2:
    timestamp  account_id currency  balance
0   2021-12-21 usdcad     USD       2
1   2021-12-21 usdcad     CAD       3
```

I would like to add a row to df1 at index 0, and fill that row with the balance of df2 based on currency. So the final df should look like this:

```
df:
    timestamp   account_id order_id  USD CAD
0   0           0          0         2   3
1   2022-01-01  usdcad     11233123  1   4
2   2022-01-02  usdcad     12313213  2   5
3   2022-01-03  usdcad     12341242  3   6
```

How can I do this in a pythonic way? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the index of `df2` to `currency` then transpose the index to columns, then append this dataframe with `df1`

```
df_out = df2.set_index('currency').T.append(df1, ignore_index=True).fillna(0)
```

---

```
print(df_out)

   USD  CAD  order_id
0    2    3         0
1    1    4  11233123
2    2    5  12313213
3    3    6  12341242
```

Comment: It works, however I am getting a row of 0s at index=1 for some reason in the original problem I have

Comment: @MathMan99 Check if your original dataframe have other columns also? If so, you can use `df2.set_index('currency')[['balance']].T.append(df1, ignore_index=True).fillna(0)`

Comment: That did not work. In my original problem, both df1 and df2 have columns that do not overlap except for the timestamp column name. However, all I care about is adding the USD and CAD columns and set everything else to 0 when appending

Comment: @MathMan99 Please update your question to include more details. Currently, the solution presented here works for the OP that you have posted.

Comment: I edited the question to better represent my current problem. Thank you!

Comment: @MathMan99 Happy coding!